# How to compare pointer and integer?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I'm trying to check if pointer is pointing at some char.

Like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define a 3
int func(char *);
int main()
{
char *s="a";
int type;
type=func(s);
printf("%d",type);

    return 0;
}
int func(char *s)
{
int type;
if(*s=="a") 
{
type=1;
}
return type;

}
```

But I constantly get warning: **warning: comparison between pointer and integer
 if(*s=="a")**

Is it possible to compare pointer and integers?

Is there another way to resolve this problem?

Can I find out at which letter is pointing *s without printing it?

Comment: Step 1: Format your code readably.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`"a"` is not a character, it is a string literal. `'a'` is a character literal, which is what you are looking for here.

Also note that in your comparison `*s == "a"` it is actually the `"a"` which is the pointer, and `*s` which is the integer... The `*` dereferences `s`, which results in the `char` (an integer) stored at the address pointed to by `s`. The string literal, however, acts as a pointer to the first character of the string `"a"`.

Furthermore, if you fix the comparison by changing it to `*s == 'a'`, you are only checking whether the *first character* of `s` is `'a'`. If you wish to compare strings, see `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

`char`s are enclosed in `''` not `""`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define a 3
int func(char *);
int main()
{
char value = 'a';
char *s=&value;
int type;
type=func(s);
printf("%d",type);

    return 0;
}
int func(char *s)
{
int type;
if(*s=='a') //or if(*s==3)
{
type=1;
}
return type;

}
```